# Why is my proxy redirecting to a different port than my API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, proxy, port, identity

I've wasted more than two weeks of one of my colleague's and my time on this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time in advance.
Here is the setup:

Web app created with Visual Studio 2022 (pre-generated code, I hardly touched the configuration and the Program.cs), **.Net Core 6.0**, **Angular 13**, **Identity**. When I launch, a command indicates that the SPA Proxy is beeing launched as well, and the URL given to me by IIS is https://localhost:**44384**. So I go on there. On there, it says that "the SPA Proxy will redirect you to https://localhost:**44484**". *Why?* It indeed redirects me to 44484. At first, I didn't care, I started working on my controllers, my UI, etc. It was not preventing the API from working at all. But now, I'm in a pickle.

Because, I now need to get the user email from my controller. Pretty basic stuff right? `HttpContextAccessor` and you're done. But *NO*! Because the ports are different! So, to make it work, you not only need to allow all CORS, which is not possible in my case because our servers admin won't let that happen, but you also need to remove a check in the Angular interceptor (`authorize.interceptor.ts`) that checks that the request bears the same origin as the `window.location.host`. This, to me, feels like removing a security check.

So I feel my solution lies with that port story. My colleague recreated a project from scratch, to compare, and his app launches the proxy on the same port as the API! What's going on? I don't want to start from scratch. And I want to understand if I can control the port the proxy is launched on. I tried simply editing the number **44484** everywhere it was in the code to **44384** but the command would just loop forever.

I don't understand and I can't find an answer online, like I'm the only developer not getting this.
Please any advice. Thanks guys.

Comment: I will start with two basic questions: did you clean your project and rebuilt it again? Also, if relevant, did you reset your IIS on your localhost?

Comment: Same problem here ! @A. Yassin  i tried to cleanup my solution and to reset IIS, but the problem IIS still here.

Comment: How about appsettings files, web.config files, or any other config-files? Some files may be used by your code that uses such port numbers. Try searching for the number 44484 in all files in your project, for example using Notepad++; Menu button Search -> Search in files.

Comment: Thank you so much @A.Yassin for not giving up on me!
As I said in the original post, I already did a Replace in Files command where I edited all occurrences of 44484 it could find. But when I do that, the command that launches the SPA proxy loops forever. And again, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same reaction, why do I need to be redirected?
It's called a proxy right, I expected that everything would run on the same port and the proxy would fix all this.

Turns out that this is by-design, and it is the other way around. Angular proxies the request to your API. If you take a look at the `proxy.conf.js` file in de ClientApp/Angular folder you will get the idea.

```js
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
 env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:38142';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
 {
   context: [
     "/weatherforecast",
  ],
   target: target,
   secure: false,
   headers: {
     Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
   }
 }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

More info on that here: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server